# Why is my echo jwt custom code not working?

Tags: go, jwt, echo

I am verifying the user using echo jwt, I am customizing while looking at the manual, but it is not applied. There are two things I want.

1. I want to proceed token check without bearer keyword
2. I want to return an error message appropriate to the situation when the token is not found or the token is invalid.

How can I modify the above code to achieve what I want?

I'm just starting to learn golang, any advice would be appreciated

```
    output := echojwt.JWT(&echojwt.Config{
        SigningKey:  []byte(key.EnvSecretKey),
        TokenLookup: "header:Authorization",
        ErrorHandler: func(c echo.Context, err error) error {
            if err != nil {
                return c.JSON(400, "custom error")
            }
            return nil
        },
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the step that you can follows:

1. Proceed token check without the "bearer" keyword: To do this, you
   can change the TokenLookup value from "header:Authorization" to
   "query:token". This will allow you to pass the token as a query
   parameter instead of in the header.
2. Return a custom error message appropriate to the situation when the
   token is not found or the token is invalid: To do this, you can
   modify the error handler function

Here's an example:

```
output := echojwt.JWT(&echojwt.Config{
     SigningKey:  []byte(key.EnvSecretKey),
     TokenLookup: "query:token",
     ErrorHandler: func(c echo.Context, err error) error {
         if err == jwt.ErrTokenNotFound {
             return c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, "token not found")
         }
         if ve, ok := err.(*jwt.ValidationError); ok {
             if ve.Errors&jwt.ValidationErrorMalformed != 0 {
                 return c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, "token is malformed")
             } else if ve.Errors&(jwt.ValidationErrorExpired|jwt.ValidationErrorNotValidYet) != 0 {
                 return c.JSON(http.StatusUnauthorized, "token is expired or not valid yet")
             } else {
                 return c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, "token is invalid")
             }
         }
         return nil
     },
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

In conclusion, I used the wrong method,

```
echojwt.JWT(&echojwt.Config{
```

instead

```
echojwt.WithConfig(echojwt.Config{
```

When using , it works normally.

As for the error handle, kha's answer was helpful.